# Api to Business Model Conversion in MVVM

Tags: swift, mvvm, business-logic

I am trying to implement MVVM structure in my new app. I have the following layers.

1. AViewControler
2. AViewModel
3. AManager
4. NetworkManager
5. CachingManager
6. ATransformer

My viewcontroller does its job perfectly fine that is rendering ui and updating views and viewmodels for the changes.

Now when I need to call an api. ViewController asks Viewmodel to fetch data. It asks Manager(repository) to fetch the data. Manager calls NetworkManager(common for full app) to call the api and get data.

Manager also creates urlrequest with body and queryparams. Manager gets the APIModel which it converts to Cachodel and gives to CacheManager to write.

My Manager gives API model back to viewmodel and based on its requirements, viewmodel converts apimodel to business using a Transformer layer.

Now I am confused between whether to give apimodel to viewmodel or convert it to businessmodel at manager layer and give businessmodel to viewmodel.

What is the best way to achieve this or if I am already doing something wrong in the architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure 100% your problem, but to me, my controller onlys know ViewModel. ViewModel will call Manager (Repository) to do any stuff (logic, network, etc) then let controller know to refresh, update, render UI... 
That way, i can follow The Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Adding to this, it seems `CachModel`, `Businessmodel` etc should also be `ViewModels` managed by the primary `ViewModel`(Or `Transformer` inside `ViewModel`) known to `ViewController`.

Comment: Where exactly should I convert apimodel to business model. In Viewmodel or manager.

Comment: To me, it should be in Manager

Comment: @Jacob. How do you name your api model and business model differently in your project when they have to be accessed outside and cannot be private.

Comment: In most of the cases, the business model and api model have the same name. In case you want to clarify and have them the specified using purpose, let make api model a generic name (might add suffix ApiModel like UserApiModel); for business model, it can be like UserProfileModel (it can be generated from UserAPIModel by a Transformer layer). So with different business logics (from different screens, flows) then the transformer layer will help you transform the models as your purpose.